# Batch 7-zip compression excluding some files FOR %%i IN (*.*)

Tags: batch-file, compression, 7zip

I have this code which I found online from another post using 7-zip I would like to zip all the files in the current folder (if sub folders can be added that would be even better). currently it works, but I would like to exclude files which have already been zipped / compressed (ex: .rar, .zip).

Is there some syntax that can exclude this for me, i.e. exclude a particular extension? Also I can not go the other way around of zipping the extensions that I want because I do not know what I will encounter.

This works zipping all files:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i" -mx=9 -ms=on -md=32m -mfb=256
```

I need something like:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.*, *NOT(.zip), NOT(.rar)*) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i" -mx=9 -ms=on -md=32m -mfb=256
```

Answer:
Since both solutions offered by @Aacini and @IZB are useful I can not pick either one of them to be the best, as they both are effective.

Comment: What has this to do with C#?

Comment: @Kelgen, your example puts each file into a separate 7z archive, is this what you need? Because in case of a single archive with all the files the answer would be `-x!` command line switch without any `for` loops.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Neh I need each file in the folder into a separate archive.
@Matyas, i`m new and the 'c#' tag got suggested sry..

Answer (score 1):

This batch command can do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "exclude=.rar.zip.7z."

set 7z=c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
dir /B>%tmp%\tmp.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%i in ("%tmp%\tmp.txt") do (
    set arc=0
    if "!exclude:%%~Xi.=!" equ "%exclude%" set arc=1
    if exist "%%~dpnxi\*" set arc=1
    if "!arc!" EQU "1" "!7z!" a "%%~ni" "%%i" -mx=9 -ms=on -md=32m -mfb=256>Nul
)
```

Comment: Yes this works, however puts them in a single archive (fixed by using "%%~ni.7z"), but also compresses my sub folders which is something that I do not need.

Also, can more be added to the if statement? as adding if "%%~xi" NEQ ".7z" (to avoid re-compressing 7z) breaks the program.

I need files to be compressed in current folder and any files under sub folders:

+root folder
  myfile.doc
  myfile2.doc
  myfile.7z
  myfile2.7z
  +subfolder
    myfile3.txt
    myfile3.7z

Comment: ok fixed the (adding to the if statement - didnt have a space before bracket), but still do not want to compress folders found within the current folder, i.e. subfolders.

Comment: Ok it is almost perfect, but this one is still compressing subfolders for me.

Comment: Try delete **if exist "%%~dpnxi\\*" set arc=1**. did this work?

Comment: Yes this worked! One last thing, is there a way to read paths from a txt file and then go through those paths?
BTW, thanks for the time of each and everyone of you!

Comment: i.e. a txt file will have:
E:\myfolder\  
E:\my2ndfolder\
E:\my2ndfolder\subfolder\
**^^ Files in each ^^**

And the compression algorithm puts the compressed files back in their respective location.

Comment: @IZB: You missed to copy this line from my solution! `rem Define the list of extensions to exclude; it *must* end in dot!`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the list of extensions to exclude; it *must* end in dot!
set "exclude=.rar.zip.7z."

rem To include subfolders, just add /R switch to next FOR
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO (
   if "!exclude:%%~Xi.=!" equ "%exclude%" do (
      rem Remove previous zip file, if any
      del "%%~ni.7z" 2>NUL
      "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i" -mx=9 -ms=on -md=32m -mfb=256
   )
)
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it re-compresses files that have the same name and puts them in the archive again. i.e. updates.
Thus if I run it twice, it will create: +myfile.7z, +myfile.7z, myfile.doc

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you. Are you saying that this solution re-compress files with .7z extension even if the `.7z.` is in the list of extensions to exclude?

Comment: Your solution when run twice (in the same folder) was re-creating another zipped file with the previously zipped file and the zipped data inside it (inception). It is ok but have to be careful not to run it twice. I thank you for your time!

Comment: Again: as written, this solution does _not_ process any file that have `.rar`, `.zip` or `.7z` extensions. Any file with `.7z` extension created in the first run will NOT be processed in a second run (unless there is a bug). Are you sure that the list of extensions ends in a dot? Try to change the place of `.7z` extension, like this: `set "exclude=.rar.7z.zip."`. Are you sure this behaviour is not caused by `7z.exe` program itself? Please, post the result: I am very interested to know if my code have a bug!

Comment: You are correct, it does not zip files with the extension .rar, .zip, or .7z, However, the "bug" (not technically a bug), is where if the program is run more than once by mistake, it will re-zip the files and the archive will contain the zipped archive (from previous zip) **+** the newly zipped data (i.e. redundant data).

This is the only reason I chose IZB`s over yours (just to be safer if given to other users to execute it). I still do appreciate your contribution and still counts as an answer!

Comment: Well, this problem may be solved in a very easy way deleting previous zip file, if any! Just insert `del "%%~ni.7z" 2>NUL` command before the `7z.exe` line (I already did this in previous code). However, be aware that this problem was _not_ stated before!

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel when 7zip has this option built-in?

> -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames